# Tkinter Minsize/Maxsize not working in basic python program

Tags: python, windows, user-interface, tkinter

The tkinter maxsize and minsize functions don't hold the size of the window.

```
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()
root.geometry("600x180")
root.minsize(600, 180)
root.maxsize(600, 1000)
root.update()
doneb = Button(root, text='Done')
doneb.pack(padx=10)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I've tried your code, and ```minsize/maxsize``` runs well on my Window 10 system.

Comment: Your code works for me on OSX.